# Can't catch an element with find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, find

I have this div:

```
<div>
    <label>Big Name
        <span class="small">Suggestion text</span>
     </label>
     <input type="text" onfocus="getSuggestion(this);">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is getting the text inside the 'span' with "getSuggestion()" function on input focus.

Here's what I tried:

```
function getSuggestion(obj) {
    var father_div = $(this).parent();

    var span = $(father_div ).find("span").html();
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Likely to be because the scope of `$(this)` is incorrect. You're passing in `obj`, do you mean to call `parent()` on that, instead of `$(this)` ??

Comment: The problem is that `this` has no meaning, it has to be `var father_div = $(obj).parent();` inside the function, or it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need double `$(..)`

try this

```
 var span = father_div.find("span").html();
```

and

```
function getSuggestion(obj) {
  var father_div = $(obj).parent();

  var span = father_div.find("span").html();
}
```

`this` in the function is named as `obj` ...

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` should be `$(obj)` and also `father_div` itself is a jQuery Element

```
function getSuggestion(obj) {
    var father_div = $(obj).parent();
    var span = father_div.find("span").html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.html()` dont return a jquery object but rather the html content of the father_div. if you wanner save the ref to it youhave to split the lines:

```
function getSuggestion(obj) {
    var father_div = $(obj).parent();
    var span = $(father_div ).find("span")
    span.html();
}
```

*and as more clever people says change this to obj*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jquery .closest(selector)

```
var span = $(this).closest('span').html();
```